# Want pie chat without percentage slice

Tags: jqplot

I want a pie chat using jqplot which will show the exact number (not percentage) inside each slice of pie chat.

$(document).ready(function(){
    var s1 = [['Sony',200], ['Samsumg',40]];

```
var plot8 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {
     seriesColors: [ "#533E6A","#B4150C"],
    grid: {
        drawBorder: false,
        drawGridlines: false,
        background: '#ffffff',
        shadow:false
    },
    axesDefaults: {

    },
    seriesDefaults:{
        renderer:$.jqplot.PieRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            showDataLabels: true,
         //   sliceMargin: 2,
         startAngle: -90
         //   diameter:30
        }
    },
    legend: {
    //    show: false,
        rendererOptions: {
            numberRows: 1
        },
        location: 's'
    }
});
```

});

Below is the jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/2032/) but it is showing the slice in percentage..instead i want the actual number(like 200 and 40).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
dataLabels='value'
```

, in the rendererOptions, as described [here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pieRenderer-js.html#%24.jqplot.PieRenderer.dataLabels). I fixed your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/2033/).